# scatter plot using Raphael JS

Tags: javascript, raphael, scatter-plot

I am looking for a javascript library for client side charting. I mainly want to produce scatter plots and interact with them. Also, I need axes to be logarithmic(That is the reason why I throwed away highcharts). I was looking at Raphael. Can somebody give me nice example of scatter plot using Raphael JS. You may also suggest alternative ways of drawing scatter plots except highcharts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is on the Raphael website - http://raphaeljs.com/github/dots.html

Comment: Thanks for replying. Actually, I was looking for something higher level than that.

Answer (score 0):

You can visit Javascript library [LightingchartJS](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js/).which have a **logarithmic axes**.
It’s been built with WebGL, so GPU assists in the rendering better than in typical HTML5/Canvas based chart libraries.
It provide interactive example for [scatter chart](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-interactive-examples/edit/lcjs-example-0900-3dScatter.html) with more than 4800 data points with great performance.
Also you can add your own data points into series which accepts data points like { x: number, y: number, z:number }

```
series.add([
    { x: 55, y: 60, z:40 },
    { x: 60, y: 62, z:40 },
    { x: 65, y: 65, z:50 }
    ])
```

For more information you can check out our [interactive examples](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-interactive-examples/) as well.

Full disclosure: I am a developer for LightningChart, I think you may find this very useful.